# How to write an output of a grep from an openssl command?

Tags: bash, grep, echo

Consider you have list of thousand IP addresses in a text file - one per line. I want to be able to grab all possible anomalies from each IP address using openssl s_client command. So far, anomalies are certificate expired, self signed certificate, and issuer **CN** to include emailAddress=root@localhost.localdomain.

Overall, I want to be able to obtain concise error message per IP address if there is any. My current bash script looks like:

```
for ip in `awk '{print $1}' < general_certs.txt`; do 
# Print IP address currently checking
echo -e $ip;
    if timeout 30 openssl s_client -connect $ip:443| grep -i 'error' ; then
# Write error information and IP address to a file
        echo `openssl s_client -connect $ip:443| grep -i 'error'` $ip >> general_errors;
    else
# Write noerror information and IP address to another file
        echo "noerror" $ip >> general_noerror;
    fi;
done
```

First issue I have with the code is that it is not optimized and that I am  skeptical if it returns accurate results. The end goal with the above script is to identify all untrusted certificate containing IPs.

Second issue I had with the above code that I could not echo $ip first because it would get truncated by the message itself. So, I ended up writing out $ip after the error message.

*It is not necessary to use openssl if there is a more genuine solution to my question.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to run them all in one shot by putting the processes in the background:

```
#!/bin/bash
max=100
counter=0
for ip in `awk '{print $1}' < general_certs.txt`; do 
    (( counter++ ))
    (
        results=$( timeout 30 openssl s_client -connect $ip:443 2> /dev/null )
        if [ "$results" = "" ]; then
            echo "$ip noresponse"
        else 
            echo -n "$ip "
            echo "$results" | grep -i 'error' || echo "noerror"
        fi
    )  >> general_errors &
    if [ $counter -eq $max ]; then
        wait
        counter=0
    fi
done
wait
```

This was the input:

```
$ cat general_certs.txt 
stackoverflow.com
redhat.com
google.com
8.8.8.8
vt.edu
bls.gov
8.8.4.4
```

This was the output:

```
$ cat general_errors
8.8.4.4 noerror
stackoverflow.com noerror
google.com noerror
vt.edu noerror
bls.gov noerror
redhat.com noerror
8.8.8.8 noresponse
```

If you have some that fail, I can test them.

Comment: I would like to choose your answer as correct but if I had oversized list of IPs, your approach would probably freeze up the OS.

Comment: Just add a counter to the loop.  When the counter reaches your max, call `wait` and reset the counter.

Comment: IP addresses were still getting truncated. Did you try to use it with IP address such as 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4?

Comment: Just put those in.  The output says "noerror", even though there was no output at all.  (Need to add code to check for that.) But it did not truncate the addresses in the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get which ip's have a untrusted certificate, you could try, even if it's not the best option, with `curl`.

Something like:

```
for ip in `awk '{print $1}' < general_certs.txt`; do 
  echo -e $ip                                                                                                                                                     

  curl https://${ip}:443 &> /dev/null                                                                                                                             

  if [ $? == 51 ]; then                                                             
    echo "upsis, https://${ip}:443 has a untrusted certificate" >> general_err
  else                                                                              
    echo "yai, https://${ip}:443 doesn't have a untrusted certificate" >> general_noerr
  fi
done
```

Notice that here you're only checking for unstrusted certificates ( error 51 in curl ), but the command could send any other error and it would go to `general_noerror`.